# Approve at the IStore but could debug on device

Tags: ios, air, adobe, app-store-connect

I have successfully upload the app using the AppLoader and the app status is "waiting for review"
but when I am trying to debug with that certificate and provisioning profile I am getting this error. (from the flash builder)

Error occurred while installing the application:
Installation Error: ApplicationVerificationFailed.

when I try to install it using IFunbox I am getting this error

Installation failed
Error# e8008015. Sorry for the inconvenience. Please send us feedback

Also could not install in using the itunes.

IOS 7.0 the device is not jailbreak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install an app built with an App Store distribution profile from any source other than the App Store without a jailbreak. If you want to test it, test it with an Ad Hoc provisioning profile and build type in the Export Release Build menu. The build is entirely identical, the only difference being what certs it is signed with.